# I get AttributeError when I use cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, image, opencv, attributeerror

I want to use the the `cv2.VideoCapture` but I get `AttributeError`.

**My Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret,frame=cap.read()
    else:
        ret=False
        ret,frame1=cap.read()
        ret,frame2=cap.read()
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        d=cv2.absdiff(frame1,frame2)
        grey=cv2.cvtColor(d,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(grey,(5,5),0)
        ret,th=cv2.threshold(blur,130,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        dil=cv2.dilate(th,np.ones((3,3),np.unit8),iterations=2)
        img,c,h=cv2.findContours(dil,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cv2.Contours(frame1,c,-1,(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow("inter",grey)

        if cv2.waitKey(40)==27:
            break
        frame1=frame2
        ret,frame2=cap.read()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()
```

**Getting error:**

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoCapture'
```

Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: Please add the full traceback. Wild guess: Did you call your own file `cv2`?

Comment: probably you saved code in `cv2.py`  so now `import cv2` loads your file instead of module `cv2` and it can't find `VideoCapture` in your file.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\pppp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2